# Using Jython with Django

Tags: python, django

How can I setup my django application to connect to mysql when using *Jython*?

## SETTINGS.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': ''django.db.backends.mysql', # should this be: com.ziclix.python.sql?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/jython/) and [django-jython docs](http://packages.python.org/django-jython/database-backends.html#mysql), you can [install `django-jython`](http://packages.python.org/django-jython/quickstart.html#install), and then use `'doj.backends.zxjdbc.mysql'` as database backend.

Also, remember to add the JDBC driver to your classpath:

```
jython -J-classpath path/to/driver.jar manage.py runserver
```

or

```
export CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:/path/to/driver.jar"
```

Comment: It worked as soon as I added the class path. jython -J-classpath path/to/mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar manage.py runserver  can you add that line and I'll take your answer.